# PYTHON How to SET pythonpath in window 10

Tags: python

I'm trying to set pythonpath but when I follow in some example in other stackoverflow, I just get a red message or nothing happened.

[image]

[image]

In my picture, u can see, no my folder  D:\DemoPython

Does anyone have exactly how to set it?, please give me some examples or the exact answer would be better. Thank so much.

Comment: You're following a guide for the plain `cmd.exe` (DOS-like) prompt, but using PowerShell. You need to match the syntax to the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for setting environment variables you found is for `cmd.exe` (the DOS-like prompt that has shipped with Windows for ages). You're running in PowerShell, which is newer, and has significantly different syntax.

On PowerShell (which you're using), you want:

```powershell
$env:PYTHONPATH = "D:\DemoPath;${env:PYTHONPATH}"
```

or

```powershell
$env:PYTHONPATH = "${env:PYTHONPATH};D:\DemoPath"
```

depending on whether you want to take precedence over existing entries or not, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >
Just add the path as
C:\Users\zee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39 (or wherever you installed python)

Comment: Setting `PYTHONPATH` persistently is usually a bad idea (if you want something installed persistently, make it actually installable with `setup.py`/`setup.cfg` or the like and install it; you won't need customized environment variables); the code it references must work (or at least be syntactically valid) in *all* versions of Python that imports it, which can be a problem (it's a huge problem when you're still mixing Py 2 and Py 3).